Какой знак препинания поставить перед сказуемым?
Технологическая схема изготовления см. "Вареное колбасное изделие".
Какой частью предложения является фраза "технологическая схема изготовления" и нужен ли знак препинания между ней и сокращённой формой глагола "смотри(те)"?
